# Running the time command produces completely different output when run with nice

Tags: ubuntu

On my heavily loaded Ubuntu box, I ran `nice -n 19 time echo` and got the following output:

```
0.00user 0.00system 0:02.80elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1732maxresident)k
312inputs+0outputs (1major+74minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

However, when I run `time echo` I get the following output instead:

```
real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Even stranger, when I run `nice -n 19 time time` I get:

```
Usage: time [-apvV] [-f format] [-o file] [--append] [--verbose]
       [--portability] [--format=format] [--output=file] [--version]
       [--quiet] [--help] command [arg...]
Command exited with non-zero status 1
0.00user 0.00system 0:03.29elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1344maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+67minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

But when I run `time time` I just get:

```
real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Why do I get different outputs when I run `time` with `nice`? I originally thought that it would just produce a higher value (e.g. real would not be 0.000s) but it seems like the `nice` command changes the `time` command.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:** Use `type` to check whether the command is a shell built-in. You're using bash's `time` in `time xyz` and `/usr/bin/time` in `nice time xyz`.

---

Use `type <command>` to learn what your shell uses:

```
$ type time
time is a shell keyword
```

In `bash` `time` is a shell keyword. It's not the `time` command (which can be found at `which time`). Multiple commands have built-in shell keywords in bash, for example `echo`, `test`, `pwd` and others:

```
$ type echo test pwd nice time
echo is a shell builtin
test is a shell builtin
pwd is a shell builtin
nice is /usr/bin/nice
time is a shell keyword
```

Note that `man` will return the wrong documentation in this case. You need `help` for shell commands:

```
$ help time
time: time [-p] pipeline
    Report time consumed by pipeline's execution.

    Execute PIPELINE and print a summary of the real time, user CPU time,
    and system CPU time spent executing PIPELINE when it terminates.

    Options:
      -p        print the timing summary in the portable Posix format

    The value of the TIMEFORMAT variable is used as the output format.

    Exit Status:
    The return status is the return status of PIPELINE.
```

`time`'s manual contains a hint, by the way:

```
$ man time

TIME(1)                 General Commands Manual                TIME(1)

NAME
       time - run programs and summarize system resource usage

SYNOPSIS
       time   [ -apqvV ] [ -f FORMAT ] [ -o FILE ]
              [ --append ] [ --verbose ] [ --quiet ] [ --portability ]
              [ --format=FORMAT ] [ --output=FILE ] [ --version ]
              [ --help ] COMMAND [ ARGS ]

DESCRIPTION
       time run the program COMMAND with any given arguments ARG....
       When COMMAND finishes, time displays information about
       resources used by COMMAND (on the standard error output, by
       default).  If COMMAND exits with non-zero status, time displays
       a warning message and the exit status.

       ...

EXAMPLES
       ...

       Users of the bash shell need to use an explicit path in order
       to run the external time command and not the shell builtin
       variant.  On system where time is installed in /usr/bin, the
       first example would become
            /usr/bin/time wc /etc/hosts
```

#### References:

- `man 1 time`
- `info bash time` or `man 1 bash` section "Pipelines" in "SHELL GRAMMAR"
- [The Linux Command line](http://www.linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php), pages 43-46.

Answer (score 2):

There are two `time` commands available. One is built into the shell, and the other is an executable on the filesystem. As you have discovered they have different output formats. `nice` can't run the one built into the shell, so it runs the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
time nice command ...
```

to use the [`time` built in to the shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html).

Or if you want to time a whole niced pipeline (which is pretty much the point of having a `time` built in to the shell), you'll need to do

```
time nice bash -c 'some cmd... | other cmd...'
```

to have the `nice` apply to the whole pipeline.